Repeated partial derivatives
Big Mathematica novice here, hopefully this isn't too trivial?
I would like to define a function in Mathematica that takes $f$ as an input and produces repeated applications of the operator $\Theta_\alpha = z_\alpha \partial_\alpha$ on $f$. Here $f$ is any function of multiple arguments $\{z_\alpha,z_\beta,\ldots\}$ and the partial derivative is a derivative w.r.t. $z_\alpha$. When repeatedly applied, the operator should not assume anything regarding the values of the indices. In particular, two applications must produce a KroneckerDelta term in case $\alpha = \beta$ :
$\Theta_\alpha \Theta_\beta f = z_\alpha \partial_\alpha [ z_\beta \partial_\beta f] = \delta_{\alpha\beta}z_\alpha\partial_\beta f + z_\alpha z_\beta \partial_\alpha\partial_\beta f$
I can write explicit formulas manually for the first few strings of $\Theta$'s, but I would like to go to high order and compute $\Theta_{\alpha_1}\ldots\Theta_{\alpha_n}f$ for high $n$ (without worrying about computation time).
I have tried to use FoldList, Nest and other such "repeated functions" but I have not managed to implement the fact that indices represented by different symbols can take the same values and therefore generate KroneckerDelta terms upon repeated applications.
Thanks in advance for your help!

I'm not entirely sure I've understood exactly, but if I've made an error maybe it's obvious enough to you to fix easily.
Theta[][f_] := f;
Theta[i_Integer][f_] := Slot[i]*D[f[##], Slot[i]] &;
Theta[i_Integer, is__Integer] := Composition @@ Theta /@ {i, is};

Demonstration:
Theta[][f]
(* f *)

Theta[2][f][x, y, z]
(* y*Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x, y, z] *)

Theta[1, 1][f][x, y, z] // InputForm
(* x*(Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, y, z] + x*Derivative[2, 0, 0][f][x, y, z]) *)

Theta[1, 2][f][x, y, z]
(* Theta[1, 2][f][x, y, z] *)

With a specific f:
f = #1^2 + #2 &;

Theta[2][f][x, y]
(* y *)

Theta[1, 1][f][x, y]
(* 4*x^2 *)

Theta[1, 2][f][x, y]
(* 0 *)

With Daniel Huber's function:
g = Sin[#1 + 2 #2 + 3 #3] &;

Theta[2][g][x, y, z]
(* 2*y*Cos[x + 2*y + 3*z] *)

Theta[2, 2][g][x, y, z]
(* y*(2*Cos[x + 2*y + 3*z] - 4*y*Sin[x + 2*y + 3*z]) *)

Theta[1, 2][g][x, y, z]
(* -2*x*y*Sin[x + 2*y + 3*z] *)

Comments:
The third definition's argument pattern is the way it is to get around the  the automatic ordering of definitions, since the other definitions use SubValues. I could have used SubValues there also, but I liked the simplicity without referring to f explicitly. The first definition is just for completeness.
Daniel's gives nice pure functions. Mine is a bit more agnostic about the function being operated on.

Thanks a lot! Your Theta definition did the trick. I have selected your answer as it was the most helpful for me compared to Daniel's pure functions, although I benefited from both approaches in my testing.

I assume that this should not depend on the names of variables. Therefore, we need to work with pure functions. E.g.
f = Function[{x, y, z}, Sin[x + 2 y + 3 z]];

or
f = Sin[#1 + 2 #2 + 3 #3]&;

To determine the number of variables, we need to distinguish these two cases:
nvar=If[StringContainsQ[ToString[f],"#"], Length@DeleteDuplicates@Cases[f1,Slot[_],Infinity],Length[f0[[1]]]];

With knowing the number of variables, we can create the body of the new function. Finally we inject the body into a pure function using Evaluate because of the attribute HoldAll. Here is the whole procedure:
der[f0_, ind_] := Module[{body, nvar, f, t},
  nvar = 
   If[(t = Length@DeleteDuplicates@Cases[f0, Slot[_], Infinity]) > 0, 
    t, Length[f0[[1]]]];
  vars = Table[Slot[i], {i, nvar}]; (*use Slot[i] as variables*)
  f = f0 @@ vars;                   (*write the function in slot variables*)
  body = Slot[ind] D[f, Slot[ind]]; (*create the body of the new function*)
  Evaluate[body] &                  (*inject the body into a pure function*)
  ]

Let us test this:
f = Function[{x, y, z}, Sin[x + 2 y + 3 z]];
der[f, 2]

2 Cos[#1 + 2 #2 + 3 #3] #2 &

Or with the other form of the function:
f = Sin[#1 + 2 #2 + 3 #3] &;

2 Cos[#1 + 2 #2 + 3 #3] #2 &

And finally a double application of der:
f = Function[{x, y, z}, Sin[x + 2 y + 3 z ]];
der[f, 2]
der[der[f, 2], 2]

2 Cos[#1 + 2 #2 + 3 #3] #2 &
#2 (2 Cos[#1 + 2 #2 + 3 #3] - 4 Sin[#1 + 2 #2 + 3 #3] #2) &

